# Application Loader For Windows

Tags: iphone, windows, xcode, macos, ios

So here I am.  I just made an iPhone app on Windows using Flash CS5.  Then, I buy the $100 apple developer program.  I create a new app and fill in the info.  Then it asks me to use the application loader to upload the app.  That is only for Mac, though.  How can I do it on a PC?  I know that a bunch of apps have been written and uploaded with microsoft computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VirtualBox should do the trick.

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but... http://www.emulators.com/softmac.htm would be worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

The only current officially supported means to create the needed certificates and to upload apps to use iTunes Connect on a Mac running Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uploading it in [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/)?

Comment: iTunes Connect now asks you to use Application Loader to upload all apps.

Answer (score 0):

To use virtual machine to run mac, you are still limited by CPU. Your cpu must support hardware virtualization, otherwise it won't even install at all.

Comment: can you provide some citation?